# How do I wait for a yield?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, generator, passport.js

I have a function `findOrCreateUser` that returns a generator. But I need to call a callback `done` when the function has completed. How do I do this?

I tried calling `next()` on the generator but the result was pending.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: fbConfig.appId,
        clientSecret: fbConfig.appSecret,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000) + '/auth/facebook/callback'
    },
    function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {

        var user = yield userRepository.findOrCreateUser(
            profile.id,
            profile.name,
            'pic');

        return user;
    })
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `co.wrap()` which "converts a co-generator-function into a regular function that returns a promise"

```
var co = require('co');

...

var findOrCreateUser = co.wrap(userRepository.findOrCreateUser)

findOrCreateUser(profile.id, profile.name, 'pic').then(function() {
    done();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. yield needs to be within a generator function and I can't make this so because the function is called by passport.

Comment: @IanWarburton Could you use co inside the passport function?

Comment: I have bluebird. I was trying to turn the generator into a promise so I could call 'then' but I couldn't find out how to turn a generator into a promise.

Comment: @IanWarburton How about now with `co.wrap()`

Comment: Yes co.wrap appears to do something useful. Except now isAuthenticated is always false. I'm so close to finishing my website... just a few more days of Javascript pain and I will go back to .net.